# Query data with odata filter

Tags: odata

I have a question about a filter query and a none filter query.

A filter query:

```
/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZRFC1_SRV/SalesOrderHeaderSet?filter=SoId eq '5000001'
```

A none filter query:

```
/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZRFC1_SRV/SalesOrderHeaderSet('5000001')
```

What is the difference between those two queries?

Answer (score 0):

- The first one returns a filtered array in a "value" property of the result object: `{"@odata.context":"...","value":[{"SoId":5000001, ...}]}`.
- The second one requests an individual entity by id `{"@odata.context":".../$entity","SoId":5000001, ...}`